Show my application's name on the Entra Id "Permissions requested" dialog
I'm using Entra Id to sign in to my Azure Static Web app. When users use my app for the very first time, while signing in they are asked to Accept permissions:

How can I customise this dialog so that my application name (and logo) are presented instead of "Azure Static Web Apps"?

What is the framework of your App?

Yes,you can change the Name and Logo from the App Registrations => Branding & properties.Image.Will check from my end once again and let you know.

Exactly which Part you want to change?

To answer your questions, my Static Web App is using Blazor WASM. As stated, I want to change the logo and the where it says "Azure Static Web Apps" in my screenshot.

Can you please cross check same for an azure app service authentication..to confirm whether it has any restrictions or any extra configuration to be done for static web app.


How can I customise this dialog so that my application name (and logo) are presented instead of "Azure Static Web Apps"?

You can change the name of the App from the Branding & properties section under the Manage in the Registered App (Entra ID).

Change the Name and Logo as per your requirement => Save.


Output:

Update:

I have cross checked with both Azure App Service and Static Web App for Blazor WASM, I am able to change the name and Logo for the Web Application.

Latest Output for Blazor WASM .NET CORE 8 deployed in Azure Static Web App.



Thanks for your answer. I just tried this and it hasn't worked immediately, i.e. I still see the same content as per my screenshot in my question. Perhaps there is some caching going on. I'll try again later.

I just had another look at this 5 days later, and I still see the same screenshot as per my question, so it hasn't worked :-(

Ok..Will check once again and let you know.

@MattFrear - Please check the update section in the answer.Can you please try it in another system or in Incognito Mode.

Also make sure you are updating the details for the same registered app (check the application id).

Thanks Harshitha for trying again. I have rechecked Entra ID and retried using a different browser, incognito mode etc, but it always shows the same "Permission requested" dialog with Azure Static Web Apps instead of the name of my application, even though it's working for you. There must be some other setting buried in Entra ID which is preventing it for me.

Can you share your code repo once.
